# When doing console.log in a function I'm getting "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, console.log

Why can't I make a function that logs my data?

If I don't do `console.log` in the function, I'm getting the values, but when doing it in a function, the data is hidden.

```
let stoneArray = [];
let beginningStone = {
  a: 200,
  b: 200,
  c: 10,
  d: 2,
  e: 5
};
stoneArray[0] = beginningStone;

function consoleData() {
  console.log('stoneArray = ' + stoneArray);
}
consoleData();
console.log(stoneArray);
```

Comment: `console.log('stoneArray = ' + stoneArray);` In the statement, you are appending to string, and so the object is appended as `[object object]`. Try logging without string. e.g - `console.log(stoneArray);`

Comment: aha, that's why. Thanks.

Comment: You can use a comma to separate the object from the string like `console.log('stoneArray = ', stoneArray);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function consoledata() {
   console.log(stoneArray)
           }
```

**Try This code **

Comment: `console.log("stoneArray = ", stoneArray);` works as well.